# using css inside jsx(changing styles inside a functional component)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a functional component that renders two divs, and I want to hide one div when the onclick function is called, which is on the other div. how do I implement that using react hooks? here is what I've got sofar.

```
const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
const hidebox = ()=> setHide(true);


<div id="cartbox" onClick={hidebox}></div>
```

how do I change the css properties here?

Comment: Try something like this, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-lop2i

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically update an element's classes based on a functional React component's state, you can do something like -

```
<div id="cartbox" onClick={hidebox} className={`${hide ? 'not-hidden' : 'hidden'}`}></div>
```

Or using inline styles you could do

```
<div id="cartbox" onClick={hidebox} style={`${hide && 'display: none;'}`}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by directly checking the state property. Return null if hidden or the DOM if not hidden

```
const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

const hidebox = ()=> setHide(true);


<div id="cartbox" onClick={hidebox}></div>
{hide ? null : <div id="divToHide" onClick={hidebox}></div>}
```